# Where does a chord of an Ellipse equal to the length of the minor axis but running parallel to the major axis cross the minor axis.

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Given an Ellipse, I need to know where a chord equal to the length of the minor axis but running parallel to the major axis cross the minor axis.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1$

Let $a>b$

the minor axis has length $2b$

We have a chord with $x$ coordinates $-b,b$ and we need to find the y coordinates.

$\frac {b^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1\\
\frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1 - \frac {b^2}{a^2}\\
y^2 = b^2(\frac {a^2 - b^2}{a^2})\\
y = \pm\frac {b}{a}\sqrt {a^2 - b^2}$

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work well for any hand drawn examples that I tried. Much appreciated.

Comment: I have a follow up question. It seems to me that for a subset of ellipses, (Eccentricity between about .099 and .37 or so) that once you find the point on the minor axis where the above chord passes through the minor axis, that all chords passing through that same point on the minor axis have the same length. Is this mathematically verifiable? This seems counter intuitive to me and may just be a result of my ellipses being a bit sloppy when I draw them. Any help on this would be appreciated.